# How to return the file path from the windows file explorer using Java

Tags: java, windows, file, jna, explorer

In my Project, I want to open the windows file explorer with java, in which you can select a file or a folder and click the "**OK**" button. Now I want to have the path of the selected file in my Javacode.

Basically like the window which pops up in every standard texteditor after you hit the "**OPEN**" button to choose the file to open in the editor.

I know how to open the windows file explorer with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe")` but I can´t figure out a way to return the file path.

Comment: Use a `JFileChooser` to get the file.

Comment: Difficult question to answer. Windows explorer really isn't meant to be used via the command line like this.  If you want to display a native file dialog then you'll need to use a JNA/JNI based solution, which is a lot of work.  Alternatively, you can do as killjoy suggests

Comment: The functionality is exposed through the [IFileOpenDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775834.aspx) interface. You'll have to learn about COM to use it, or find a prebuilt library that wraps it for you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how I'd use a JFileChooser for your problem:

```
String filePath;    // File path plus name and file extension
String directory;        // File directory
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        directory = fc.getSelectedFile().getName();
    } else {
        directory = "Error in selection";
    }
filePath = directory + "\\" + folderName;
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use `JFileChooser` class in `javax.swing.JFileChooser`. It's a Java swing object so it won't invoke the native OS's file browser but it does a good job at selecting a file/saving to a location. Take a look at this [link](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/JavaAndDS/files/io6JFileChooser.pdf) on basic implementation of it.

I used this method from the link in my code:

```
public static Path getInputPath(String s) {
        
         /*Send a path (a String path) to open in a specific directory
         or if null default directory */
         JFileChooser jd = s == null ? new JFileChooser() : new JFileChooser(s);

         jd.setDialogTitle("Choose input file");
         int returnVal= jd.showOpenDialog(null);

         /* If user didn't select a file and click ok, return null Path object*/
         if (returnVal != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) return null;
         return jd.getSelectedFile().toPath();
    
    }
```

Note that this method returns a Path object, not a String path. This can be changed as needed.